# using an if statement in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

is it possible to use an if staement in a where clause?

i.e.

`WHERE (underwritername = 'underwriter') 
and (case when inceptiondate is null then 
          (requestdate >= convert(datetime,'01/10/2009',103))
     else
   (Inceptiondate >= convert(datetime,'01/10/2009',103))
     ) 
and (requestdate <= convert(datetime,'31/10/2010',103))`

basically if one column is null, i need to use an alternative column for selection.

Many Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that using the `CASE` statement a little different:

```
WHERE (underwritername = 'underwriter') 
and (case when inceptiondate is null 
     AND requestdate >= convert(datetime,'01/10/2009',103) THEN 1 
     WHEN inceptiondate IS NOT NULL 
     AND Inceptiondate >= convert(datetime,'01/10/2009',103) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
and (requestdate <= convert(datetime,'31/10/2010',103))
```

Comment: fantastic.. thankyou.. My brain gets the logic, but the syntax always eludes me. :)

Comment: for some reason this is no longer working for me.. either my previous data was tricking me or i have changed something..

Comment: @Adaam McC do you have test data?. or provide me the complete code you are using?, cause the way it is, it should work the way you wanted to.